# Get reference to main class from a property

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a class Class1 with several properties (Property1, Property2, ...)

For some design reasons, I have access only to, let's say, Property1.

Is there a way to get a reference to Class1 ?

I tried Property1.Parent, Property1.Base but both failed.

I'm using a heavy workaround which is creating a separate class for each property with a reference to the main class:

```
Public Class DerivedProperty1
    Inherits Property1

    Public ParentClass as Class1

    Public Sub New(ParentClass as Class1)
        me.ParentClass = ParentClass
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then Class1 will become

```
Public Class Class1
    Public DerivedProperty1 as DerivedProperty1
    ...
End Class
```

Is there another way different from this workaround ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have only the value of the property? Or do you have an expression that is a (property) selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing build for that.

That's because the `Class1.Property` property really just hides a reference to a `Property1Class` class instance stored somewhere else. And because of that, the same `Property1Class` instance can be referenced by more then one `Class1` instances.

And your naming in misleading. `Property1Class` class does not derive from `Class1` class. It's just used by that class as a type of one of properties.

So if you need that kind of functionalty, you have to code it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading naming. I corrected the inheritance feature.